# Reassigning in list

Tags: python, list, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to reassign 'hello' with 'goodbye' in the list, but the reassigning is happening at incorrect positions

Using Jupyter Notebook

```
list3 = [1,2,[3,4,'hello']]
 
list3[2][2]= 'goodbye'
list3
[1, 'goodbye', [3, 4, 'goodbye']]
```

I am gettig the above result. I only want to reassign 'hello'.

Comment: I can't reproduce that. https://ideone.com/zwVkMp

Comment: It could happen in some other situations where you have multiple references to the same list. But not in the code you showed. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly

Comment: Works fine for me in IDLE

Comment: Maybe in jupyter something different

Comment: This works in jupyter also

Answer (score 1):

**Drshanu**

I tried the code from my side.

But the results are very good.

```
list3 = [1,2,[3,4,'hello']]

list3[2][2]= 'goodbye'

print(list3)
```

*Result*

```
[1,2,[3,4,'goodbye']]
```

So I think you should post all your code unless it's the private code.

Then I will review and reply again.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to repeat with a new list and see what happens and will let you know.